std::ranges::sort not working with non-default operator<=>?
I have a case when struct type needs non-default operator<=> - just not all fields are important when defining order of objects.
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b; // not important when ordering
    int c;

    constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A& rhs) const
    {
        if (const auto res = a<=>rhs.a; res != 0) return res;
        return c<=>rhs.c;
    }
};

To my surprise, I cannot use container with this type as an argument to std::ranges::sort:
std::array<A, 100> aa{};
std::ranges::sort(aa);

I checked it on newest gcc (14) and clang (19) and it basically claims that the range is not sortable because std::invocable_v<std::ranges::less&, A&, A&> is not true.
See godbold link
More observations:

It works with std::sort (std::sort(aa.begin(), aa.end());)
It works when adding non-default operator==
And it works with default (=default) operator<=>

Is this compilers bug, C++ standard bug or some strange C++ rules play here and it should be that way?
If the last option is correct - can you provide justification for such behavior?

Update:
From the comments it seems that std::ranges::less{}(A{}, A{}) requires not only operator< (derived from operator<=>) but also operator== that cannot be derived from non-default operator<=> so the error.
But the one question remains - why std::ranges::less needs operator==?
And better example from comments: link

A side note: regarding your check res != 0, AFAIK operator<=> is not guaranteed to return any specific numeric value, but rather std::strong_ordering::... or std::partial_ordering::....

Non-default <=> doesn't generate == because it's slow in general (e.g. for strings == can compare sizes and stop early if not equal, while <=> can't). And even when you do default <=>, the generated == isn't implemented in terms of that <=> (because, again, slow) but rather compares every field for equality. ...And ranges don't like the missing ==, they want all 6 comparison operators to be valid even if they don't call them.

ranges algorithms have stronger requirement than regular algorithm. (as having all comparisons instead of just <).

A custom operator<=> means you don't get a compiler synthesized operator==.

@Eljay ok, but 2 questions: why std::ranges::sort needs operator== and why std::sort works just fine? And compilation error tells std::ranges::less{}(A{}, A{}) is not working...

@wohlstad AFAIK 0 is an exception here and can be compared... think about cases when we do not if this is strong or weak ordering - and 0 is universal...

"AFAIK 0 is an exception here and can be compared"  Causes a compiler error on my machine. As per std::ranges::less "Unlike std::less, std::ranges::less requires all six comparison operators <, <=, >, >=, == and != to be valid (via the totally_ordered_with constraint)." (That's not normative with the standard, so I don't consider it a suitable language-lawyer reference.)

@Eljay - either you compiler is wrong or cpprefrence is wrong: "Comparison operators are defined between values of this type and literal ​0" - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering. But this is completely out of this question

@PiotrNycz I am not a language lawyer, but it seems like you are right. And the same statement is in the documentation for std::partial_ordering (and std::weak_ordering) as well.

Tweaked MCVE: https://godbolt.org/z/MMvxTfzP5

@MarekR That is the version I need: https://godbolt.org/z/1EWToTo7c  - you forget about repeating operator<=> in Version==2

To answer the final question: ranges::less::operator() does not use any operator other than <. But this function is constrained to types modelling the totally_ordered concept.

@TobySpeight but why? Why std::ranges::less requires totally_ordered - or why totally_ordered means they can be equal-compared? When definining order in mathematical sense, AFAIR (I learnt math about half century ago), no equal-comparing is needed

Possibly more readable version of your <=>: private: constexpr auto sortkey() const { return std::tie(a, c); } public: constexpr auto operator<=>(const A& other) const { return sortkey <=> other.sortkey(); } constexpr auto operator==(const A& other) const { return sortkey == other.sortkey(); } 

Just a guess, but I expect std::totally_ordered requires all the comparisons to be defined because doing so makes it easier for users to get the behaviour they expect when they use == or !=).  I.e. a convenience for users of types rather than the implementer.  Which makes sense, since most types have more users than implementers.  But perhaps that question is close enough that this is now a duplicate?

Sorting algorithms rely on the fact that the items being sorted are totally ordered (in the mathematical sense). This means that there is an order that is reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric and, in order to be a total order, strongly connected, which means that for any a and b,
a <= b || b <= a

or:
if (a != b) then a <= b or b <= a

and because of the antisymmetry requirement, it's EITHER a <= b OR b <= a. This again implies that for any collection a, b, c, ... there exists a permutation x, y, z, ... such that x <= y <= z <= ..., or in other words: The collection can be sorted.
So the constraint for ranges::less that its operands must be totally ordered exists not only for the purpose of requiring that certain operators are available, but also to indicate the operators must have certain semantics. Algorithms can then be written under the assumption that the available operators have these semantics.
This is why concepts in C++20 often have semantic requirements in addition to type requirements. Semantic requirements are not enforced by the compiler, but developers are supposed to honor them when defining a type that models a concept, and as a result, when a type models a concept, developers can assume that the type also fulfills all semantic requirements of the concept.
If a type is totally ordered, then all the comparison operators are well-defined for it and can be (mathematically) inferred from just the < operator. Therefore, the totally_ordered concept requires that all operators are available, simply because it is meaningful for a totally ordered type, and because it is easy to define all operators using the <=> operator.
However, for performance reasons, the compiler does not automatically generate the == operator when a type has a custom <=> operator, because <=> potentially cannot be implemented as efficiently as ==, and it is not guaranteed that the implicitly provided == operator would have the same semantics as if it was implemented in terms of the (custom) <=> operator. For example, when comparing strings, == can have O(1) time complexity for strings that have different length, whereas <=> cannot.
Therefore, if <=> is not defaulted, you have to explicitly define == in order for all comparison operators to be defined, which is required to model the concept totally_ordered, which is required by ranges_less, which is used by ranges::sort, because sorting algorithms require total order in order to work as designed.
See also this answer to a different question.

The first part is incorrect. Sorting isn't based on <=, it's based on < (strict) - the comparison must be irreflexive, not reflexive.  It also does not require a total order, only a weak order. So rather than a requirement of trichotomy (a ==b || a < b || a > b is how that's usually phrased), we have a requirement of transitivity of equivalence.

@Barry Sorting can be based on <= or <. This is a choice of implementation, especially with std::ranges::sort, since it requires both operators to be available. Order relations can be defined using either operators. I used <=, because so do Wikipedia and most math textbooks. You are probably right, though, that sorting only requires a weak order. If we also consider the fact that every type T that supports all comparison operators models totally_ordered even if the order is not necessarily total, it is possible that C++ simply got it wrong.

No it cannot, the wording is clear that the comparison must be irreflexive: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting

@Barry Comparison functions passed to sorting algorithms in the C++ standard library must be irreflexive (but std::ranges::less still requires that all operators are available). An order in the mathematical sense, which is what I am referring to, can be defined based on a reflexive or irreflexive relation.

This is a question about std::ranges::sort — what's relevant is what std::ranges::sort requires. Yes, in the broader mathematical sense, sure, but that's just not relevant here, and is actively misleading in this context.

@Barry The mathematical context was given for the purpose of explaining the mathematical concept of a total order, which was used to explain the requirements of std::ranges::sort. So the choice of <= is not incorrect, only confusing (as proven by your comment). I can change this. Let's rather talk about the fact that sorting doesn't require a total order but only a weak order, where my answer was actually incorrect. Is std::totally_ordered simply misnamed, or does std::ranges::sort unnecessarily require std::equality_comparable? What do you think is the case here?

In general, the std::ranges algorithms are a lot more constrained than the std:: ones. The goal isn't to provide the absolute minimal set of operations that the algorithms need, but rather a cohesive model of operations.
In this case, all the ordering-based algorithms do require both ordering and equality. In several other languages, you cannot even opt into ordering without also providing equality. It's the weaker functionality, so it makes sense to have both.
So std::ranges::sort(aa) fails because while A provides an ordering (<=>) it doesn't provide equality (==). So your options are:

either provide a corresponding == operator (that likewise does not look at b), or
provide a custom ordering to sort (that would not look at b).

Note that ranges algorithms do support projections, so the latter might look like:
std::ranges::sort(aa, std::ranges::less(), [](A const& a){ return std::tie(a.a, a.c); });

Which you can wrap in a cute adapter like this:
std::ranges::sort(aa, std::ranges::less(), by(&A::a, &A::c));


Why do you prefer to construct a std::ranges::less with the use of parentheses, opposed to using curly braces?

Thanks for the hints. Alternatively I can just derive operator== from operator<=> by hand - like bool operator==(...rhs) const { return (*this<=>rhs)==0; }. I do not like to overuse std::tuple for it causeing compilation time/compilation memory  increase.

@303 I only use braces when I very specifically want to use the meaning that braces provide - aggregate initialization or invoking an initializer_list constructor. Otherwise, I always use parentheses. It's the path of least possible surprise.

So, you don't find any sentiment in the rationale given by the C++ Core Guidelines rule ES.23: Prefer the {}-initializer syntax? I've always considered preventing narrowing conversions during initialization to be a good thing, hence preferring to default to using curly braces.

@303 Not even close, no. It's hard to call something "safer" and "less ambiguous" when it's the one whose meaning you cannot be sure of.
